# Error 'Unknown column 'branch' in 'field list'' on query. Default database: 'db'

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, mysql-error-1054, mysql-error-1062

I get the following replication error in `SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;`

```
Error 'Unknown column 'branch' in 'field list'' on query. Default database: 'db'.
```

The replication also has been stopped due to this.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the Last_Errno row the error code of the error that caused replication to stop is 1054 (Unknown column '%s' in '%s'). If you want the MySQL slave to ignore such errors, just open your my.cnf (on Debian and Ubuntu it's /etc/mysql/my.cnf)...

1. Edit the my.cnf

   vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
2. You can skip multiple errors or only 1054

   slave-skip-errors = 1062,1054
3. Restart MySQL

   /etc/init.d/mysql restart